# Understanding file permissions

Tags: linux, security, file-permissions

What is the ending `r` for and the leading `d` for in file permissions on Linux?

Example:

```
drwxr-xr-x
```

I know about the user, group, others part, and I know `w`=write, `r`=read, `x`=execute.

But I don't know about the leading `d` and the trailing `r`.

Can anyone explain how this works?

Answer (score 7):

- `d` means that the listing is a directory
- `r` means the item can be read
- `w` means the item can be written to (EG: modified)
- `x` means the item can be executed (EG: a script or program)

There are three sets of `rwx` permissions, which correspond to (in order from left-to-right):

- the current owner
- the current group
- other users

Answer (score 6):

The leading `d` means the entry is a directory; other possibilities include:

- `l` - [Symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link)
- `s` - [Setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid)
- `t` - [Sticky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit)

I don't know what trailing `r` you're referring to, there isn't one in your example

Answer (score 2):

The hyphens in your examples aren't separators. They're placeholders for where the w's would go, so show that "group" and "others" don't have Write permission.

`drwxr-xr-x` is read like this: `d rwx r-x r-x`

`d` - directory

`rwx` - user (owner) has Read, Write, and eXecute.

`r-x` - group has Read and eXecute (but not Write).

`r-x` - others have Read and eXecute (but not Write).

I think you were misreading the hyphens as separators between the u/g/o sections, like this:

`drwxr - xr - x`, which would explain why you thought the r's were "trailing".